# Powershell string parm with optional value (or switch parm with string value)

Tags: powershell-2.0

I want my script to accept an **optional** "-build" parameter that **also optionally** specifies a build target.  If the user specifies -build without specifying a value, a default target will be used.  so

```
doit.ps1
```

would not do a build. (it does other stuff)

```
doit.ps1 -build
```

would build c:\source\myproj.sln

and

```
doit.ps1 -build c:\otherssource.sln
```

would of course build that project.

I can't see how to do this. A string parm, if specified, requires a value, and a switch parm doesn't support a value.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in PowerShell a parameter used as a switch, which is your first case can't be valued and a parameter which is not a switch need a value. Here is a piece of code that should help you to address your problem using `$PSBoundParameters`.

```
Param
(
  #[CmdletBinding()]
  [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [switch]$Builddefault,
  [String]$Build
)

Write-host 'Hello'

if ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -contains 'Builddefault')
{
  Write-Host "Builddefault is present"
}

if ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -contains 'Build')
{
  Write-Host "Build is present"
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is pretty easily solved by using two parameters.  My goal is to use one.